# FB App Not Appearing After Submitting to App Center

Tags: facebook, flash, heroku

I have two Facebook app built with Flash and Heroku. I submitted one to the App Center and now the Flash doesn't show up:

http://apps.facebook.com/punchromney

However, this one has not been submitted to the App Center and it works fine:

http://apps.facebook.com/punchobama

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It can take several minutes to propagate to the app server. Wait until then and check back.

Comment: Does the app have to be approved by Facebook before it shows up? It was working fine yesterday before I submitted it to the App Center.